# VS Code: Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I recently had some big errors with my Ubuntu 18.04 partition and followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/148820). Now most things on my computer are working fine. However, I can't launch VS Code. I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it. I tried the snap version and the `.deb`. Neither have solved this error:

```
code --verbose
[18788:0625/203233.207446:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[main 2020-06-26T00:32:33.273Z] Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir
[main 2020-06-26T00:32:33.275Z] Lifecycle#kill()
```

Code version is 1.46.1.

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90869) answer makes me think it doesn't have to do with VS Code - maybe something with `libc6`? But I'm not sure. Other people with this error seemed to have multiple other errors, so when they resolved those errors, this one went away too.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the first error (`sandbox_linux`) I ran:

```sh
code --verbose --disable-gpu
```

That error is probably always there and I just never noticed it before.

The second error I finally got rid of by deleting my [VS Code settings directory](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/):

```sh
rm ~/.config/Code -rf
```

I think VS Code couldn't edit/open that directory or its files for some reason.