# No student can install extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

We are a school and would like to use Visual Studio Code together with the Omnisharp extension.

The students' working environment has the following characteristics

- Server-stored home directories
- Active Directory environment
- Samba 4.x is used as Active Directory domain controller
- Students do not have write access to C:.
- Extensions are provided locally as a .vsix
- file Access to the Marketplace is not permitted
- --extensions-dir=H:\vscode\ext is used to redirect the extension directory to the student's server-stored home directory when starting Visual Studio Code.

Unfortunately, no student can install an extension (.vsix). The following error appears

```
[2021-12-06 11:20:42.962] [renderer1] [error] ["Extract: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'H:\\vscode\\extensions\\.819a7632-05f1-4909-b81c-aaf7c669f02b\\.debugger\\cs'","    at s.extractAtLocation (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:188875)","    at async s.extractUserExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:185594)","    at async q.extract (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:198974)","    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:199612)"]
[2021-12-06 11:20:42.988] [renderer1] [error] EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'H:\vscode\extensions\.819a7632-05f1-4909-b81c-aaf7c669f02b\.debugger\cs': Extract: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'H:\vscode\extensions\.819a7632-05f1-4909-b81c-aaf7c669f02b\.debugger\cs'
    at s.extractAtLocation (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:188875)
    at async s.extractUserExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:185594)
    at async q.extract (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:198974)
    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:199612)
```

I cannot understand this error. Can someone explain it to me? The students do not have write permissions to C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code.... Can this be the reason?

Within my private environment, the installation works under similar conditions.

Comment: have you looked at all the command line options, you can change the directory where VSC stores the extensions

Comment: In fact, I used the command 
code --extensions-dir=path-to-dir instead of code --extensions-dir path-to-dir. I have an equal sign between --extensions-dir and path-to-dir. But I'm not sure if that's the reason.

Comment: please provide as much/exact info as possible(better "edit" post, than in comment;) ..meanwhile have a look at [VS Code: Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62586301/592355)  ... and i feel the root of  the problem/solution you already named: "..we redirect the installation directories for the vscode extensions to the students' server-stored home directories when VScode is started"

Comment: This question isn't really about programming, but rather software installation. It is probably better suited for https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/